# Replace &amp; with & (apache)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have some this plugin in WP that adds another `$_GET` var to the string whenever it needs to refresh itself. The problem is when the new `&something=1` is added the previous ones change from `&` to `&amp;` and my other CMS fails to detect them. Is there a way from htaccess or apache options to redirect the `&amp;` to `&`. Now it won't and it stays in the address bar like it's set `&amp;`.

PS: This is problem in the http server, because it's fresh installed it happens not only in this case but in many others where the php generates `&amp;` and is not converted to `&`.

I installed fresh apache2 on Debian wheezy. Dunno which part of the configuration is messed up

I tried;

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD) (.*)&amp;(.*) HTTP/[\d.]+$
RewriteRule %2&%3 [R]
```

It didn't  worked out ..

Comment: Use `\s` in place of spaces when matchign `THE_REQUEST`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.*?)\&amp\;([^\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1&%2 [L,NE,R]
```

This works fine so far !